# C shell doing arithmetic operations with large numbers

Tags: shell, unix, csh

First of all: sorry for using c shell, blame my company not me. I hate the damn thing as much as most of you do now (at first I was like, hey this ain't so bad).

I am trying to subtract large numbers obtained from time stamps. Here is what I am trying:

```
set curTime = `date +%s%N`
#... some stuff
@curTime = `date +%s%N` - $curTime #get the diff
echo "time taken: $curTime"
```

However I guess the numbers are too big - before I tried with just seconds and it worked fine. Here's what I see in the log:

```
@curMilli = 1349996279792995000 - 1349996279170458000
@curMilli: Command not found.
```

As I said I do the exact same thing with `date +%s` and it's fine, so I'm assuming it's something about the largeness of the numbers.

How can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language has a short section "Using bc in shell scripts".

Comment: Thanks for that. Could I get some help on modifying my command? I've tried `@curMilli = 1349996279792995000 - 1349996279170458000 | bc` without success; I've also tried variations with parenthesis () surrounding parts of the expression, to no avail.

Comment: I think you need a semi-colon. `echo  "1349996279792995000 - 1349996279170458000;" | bc` gives `622537000`.

Comment: That's great! And if I wrap in those sideways ticks `` it seems to work in variable assignment. Go ahead and post and answer to get accepted bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language has a short section "Using bc in shell scripts".   A test:

```
set curTime = `/bin/date +%s%N`
/bin/sleep 2
set prevTime = $curTime
set curTime = `/bin/date +%s%N`
set diff = `echo "$curTime - $prevTime;" | /usr/bin/bc`
echo $diff
```

will give (with the digits after the initial `20` variable):

```
2016204108
```

P.s:  I wish I could vote you up twice for `"I hate the damn thing as much as most of you do now (at first I was like, hey this ain't so bad)."`